# Why am I getting TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm creating a string that I an then use in a method that queries a mongodb collection.  Eventually the dates will be from user input.  Here's the relevant code and string:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
import time
import datetime
start_yr    = 2015
start_mnth  = 2
start_day   = 1
end_yr      = 2015
end_mnth    = 2
end_day     = 28

# this is the line called in the error
created_at_string = { "created_at": {"$gte" : datetime(start_yr, start_mnth, start_day),"$lt" : datetime(end_yr, end_mnth, end_day)}}
```

The idea will be to use `created_at_string` as an argument in more complex query methods.

I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 218, in <module>
    program.runProgram()
  File "main.py", line 61, in runProgram
    report.RcreateReport()
  File "/filepath/report.py", line 95, in RcreateReport
 created_at_string = { "created_at": {"$gte" : datetime(start_yr, start_mnth, start_day),"$lt" : datetime(end_yr, end_mnth, end_day)}}
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Why?

Comment: Are you sure you did `from datetime import datetime` and not just `import datetime`?

Comment: Is that your whole code and is there a typo? I bet you did `import datetime` and tried to call the module...

Comment: Also, the *full* traceback could be nice. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I added the full traceback and double checked my imports.  I have `from datetime import datetime` and then `import time` and then 
`import datetime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found your issue:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import datetime
```

Let's look at this in order:

In your `globals`, you have something called `datetime`, a function. Then, you import `time`, a module object. Then, you import `datetime`, hence overwriting your `datetime` function. Here's an example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime(2015, 05, 26)
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 26, 0, 0)
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime(2015, 05, 26)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime(2015, 05, 26)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>>
```

No matter what, even if you change the order, you will overwrite something, be it the function or module objects. So, just rename something:

```
import datetime
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

Comment: I think this is it.  To complete the thought, in the query string, I would have to replace `datetime` with `dt`, correct?

Comment: That's correct. Otherwise, you'd be calling a module like before! :)