# datastore client add query filter issue 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable '

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Getting an error when trying  to add date filter to the query. Not sure what is causing it. Code is run in app engine flex environment.

Error

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Cron job

```
computation_cron= Blueprint('cron.stock_data_transformation', __name__)
@computation_cron.route('/cron/stock_data_transformation')
def cron():
    ds = datastore.Client(project="earningspredictor-173913")
    query = ds.query(kind='StockPrice')
    query.add_filter('date', '>', datetime(2016,01,01))
    dataframe_data = []
    temp_dict = {}
    for q in query.fetch(limit=1000):
          temp_dict["stock_code"] = q["stock_code"]
```

Comment: referring to solution of this question resolved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469445/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469445/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-in-python)